# Best way to track occurrences of an element using a Database

Tags: c++, sql-server

I'm developing an application that recognizes an element, given a library of models.

This library is saved in a local Database in one table. This table contains the model identification number, its name, and the number of times that it was recognized. This last parameter is used because I developed a specific application for the organization of that library, and I want short all the models by how many time each one was matched.

The application that matches the current element with the models saved in the library, run in the same PC and have access at the model library database.

What is the best way to track the number of occurrences in which a model was recognized with the element under analysis?

One solution can be: execute a query and increment by one the match count value in the model's table every time that I match it, but I'm scared due to the fact that I have to perform a match operation every 2/3 second. With this solution, I will query verbosely the database I think.

Another useful information can be obtained, thanks to the fact that I save in a table in the same database, the history of elements under analysis with their match result for elaboration purpose. Maybe when I start the application referred to manage the model's library, I can count the number of occurrences for each model from the history table and update the model's match count. But I have more or less 20.000 candidates for the matching per day, and I'm planning to clear the history table each day/month, and now a day in this table I don't save the date.

Thanks in advice

Comment: What are the structures of your tables?

Comment: The model table is structured as: | modelId  INT PRIMARY KEY | name VARCHAR(50) | matchCount INT DEFAULT 0 |. The history table (aka. production table) is: | objectId PRIMARY KEY | timestamp TIMESTAMP | encoderValue INT | matchResult VARCHAR(50) |. Today I updated the table adding the acquisition timestamp.

Comment: The frequency of updating the Model table every 2-3 seconds is not high at all. I don't foresee any problem querying the database at this rate, especially that you have a primary key on ModelId.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me. I'm only trying to find "the best way" to do this simple and stupid task.